# R prophet select dates

Tags: r, list, facebook-prophet

I have a question about R prophet. I can plot the forecast using:

```
  plot(
  prophet_plot[[1]],
  prophet_plot[[2]])
```

However, I would like to plot only the past X data points before the forecast and the forecast itself.

Namely, I am using data from 2013-01-01 until 2018-11-25 and making a forecast until 2018-12-25. What I would like to see on the plot is the data+forecast from 2015-11-25 until 2018-12-25.

So basically an `xlim`, but on a Prophet object.

Could someone help me with this?

Cheers,
Irina

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we can work with?